# How to permanently change category of new incoming outlook email with vba?

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2007

I am trying to do the following when I receive new email:

> Sub CheckReadReceipt(myMail As Outlook.MailItem)
>
> ```
> If (myMail.ReadReceiptRequested = True) Then
>     myMail.Categories = "Read Receipt Requested"
>     myMail.Save
>     'MsgBox "Read receipt for " & myMail.Subject & " found!"
>     'eventually do something more creative..
> End If
>
>  End Sub
> ```

Unfortunately, it doesn't actually save the category of the newly received email - I am obviously missing something here.

I am calling this via a rule on all incoming email (this is successfully processed by viewing the MsgBox correctly).

Comment: The code looks fine.  Is "Read Receipt Requested" actually a valid category?  What do you get if you read the value of myMail.Categories in your MsgBox?  Also, any chance you are using the *Clear categories on mail* rule which if run after would delete your category?

Comment: @LukeZ it is a valid category (the message box is triggered when receiving this type of email when uncommented). I am not clearing categories.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this one, this frustrated me for a while, strangely solution was to change your function call:

```
myMail.Save
```

to

```
myMail.Save()
```

I think visual basic thinks `Save` as a property and not a method.